CSS-Grid design choice
I am new to web development and I have a design choice question. I am developing a game where students can learn how to multiply. Now I run into a problem regarding displaying the multiplication. I am not sure on how to format the individual input cells for a multiplication since. The following picture might make my problem a little bit more clear. 
Since I don't know how many or if any fields(white boxes) and carrys(red boxes) occur I am not sure how to go from here.
I am using Django and I have tried to create a grid(not a css grid) of all possible boxes for that calculation and set the display flag to true if that box is neccesary for my calculation. Doing this it did not feel right. There must be an easier way. Would css-grid be the right choice for this type of problem? So I just pass all my boxes to the view and the css will handle the rest.
Thanks in advance

yes cds-grid can solve this. however you need to use double of the columns for the 50% offset and then let the boxes span 2 columns.

It would help us if you could include the code you have so far. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

I would suggest css as well. Specifically, the "grid-row-templates" and "grid-column-templates". It will be and easire way to see how the info is presented and make it responsive.
